# z-index and float: right not playing well together

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a couple of problems one with **z-index** and the other with **float: right;**.

I want to have an icon to display a cross that the user can click to dismiss a notification, this is appearing on the top right of the notification that appears at the bottom of the page.

What I have noticed is that the z-index does not have any effect on the div with the style class `dismiss`, no matter what I change the various divs to use. The mouse cursor does not change on hover and the click listener is not invoked when I click on the icon.

The second issue is the `float: right;` div with the style class `notifyRight` appearing in the wrong place. It is *intended* to appear on the same line as the `notifyLeft`, `notifyCenter` classed divs, but it's appearing on the line below.

Is what I am trying to do better done another way, as I cannot work out how to fix these two problems.

[image: Example of output from the code.]

Source code below or you can http://jsfiddle.net/3cGRN/.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">
        <div id="notificationContainer" class="anchor-for-absolute-positioning">
            <div id="dismiss" class="dismiss">
                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-application-exit-icon.png" title="Dismiss notification message." />
            </div>
            <div id="first" class="use-anchor">
                <div class="notifyLeft">
                    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/48/Button-Info-icon.png" style=" display: block;">
                </div>
                <div class="notifyCenter">
                    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/cat/128/Cat-Black-White-icon.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="notifyRight">
                    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/48/Button-Info-icon.png" style=" display: block;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.anchor-for-absolute-positioning {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(176, 226, 255);
    width: 100%;
    height: 128px;
}
.use-anchor {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.dismiss {
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
.notifyLeft {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#CC6600;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.notifyCenter {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 50px 0 50px;
    background-color:#FFCC00;
}
.notifyRight {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#FF6633;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dismiss').click(function() { alert('click'); });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (i.e a value other than static, which is the default). Add `position:relative` to your `.dismiss` class and you can click the element:

```
.dismiss {
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3cGRN/1/)**

Then, to get your notify icon on the same line, re-order your HTML to:

```
<div class="notifyLeft">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/48/Button-Info-icon.png" style=" display: block;">
</div>
<div class="notifyRight">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/48/Button-Info-icon.png" style=" display: block;">
</div>
<div class="notifyCenter">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/cat/128/Cat-Black-White-icon.png" />
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3cGRN/5/)**

Comment: Thanks, that's the first one! Any idea for the float: right; issue?

Comment: + 1 - Dang it you beat me to it.

Comment: Is this because the center div is of unknown width, so it needs to know the right hand side first? I don't really understand the reasoning for the ordering change.

Comment: The order needs to be changed because you need to push the left and right floated elements out of the way for the center element to float up to occupy the space between them.

Comment: Got it... `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;` on the image.